# print tag value from xml using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to write a Python script that prints the value of a particular tag in an XML output. Here, the tag value I need to print is the value of  in each and every occurrences in the XML output. I tried as below, but it shows an attribute error. What could be wrong here? Which is the correct way of getting and print values of certain more tags which I am interested to see? Any help please? Thanks.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mystring="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main>
    <student>
        <male>
            <result>pass</result>
            <name>Paul</name>
            <address>boston</address>
            <localreference>
                <name>Charlie</name>
            </localreference>
        </male>
        <female>
            <result>pass</result>
            <name>Rose</name>
            <address>newyork</address>
            <localreference>
                <name>Charlie</name>
            </localreference>
        </female>
    </student>
    <student>
        <male>
            <result>fail</result>
            <name>Philippe</name>
            <address>boston</address>
            <localreference>
                <name>White</name>
            </localreference>
        </male>
    </student>
</main>"""

main = ET.fromstring(mystring)
for student in main:
  if (student.tag == "student"):
      print student.find("male/result").text
      print student.find("female/result").text
```

Error>

```
# python new5.py
pass
pass
fail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new5.py", line 39, in <module>
    print student.find("female/result").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElementTree supports a subset of [XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), and that may be easier for your example:

```
root = ET.fromstring(mystring)
for gender in ('male', 'female'):
    print gender
    for student in root.findall('./student/%s' % gender): 
        print '\t{:20}: {}'.format(student.find('name').text, student.find('result').text)
```

Prints:

```
male
    Paul                : pass
    Philippe            : fail
female
    Rose                : pass
```

(btw: avoid using `main` as a variable name since you clobber the name of the `main` module)

---

If you want the results in document order rather than grouped by gender, you might do something like:

```
for students in root.findall('./student'):
    for gender in students:
        print ' '.join([gender.tag] + map(lambda a: gender.find(a).text, ('name', 'address', 'result', 'localreference/name')))
```

Prints

```
male Paul boston pass Charlie
female Rose newyork pass Charlie
male Philippe boston fail White
```

Comment: Thanks Dawg.  However i get this error. # python new5.py
male
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new5.py", line 40, in <module>
    print '\t{:20}: {}'.format(student.find('name').text, student.find('result').text)
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: What version os Python? You probably have Python 2.6. Use `'\t{0:20}: {1}'` for the format string.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I am using 2.6.6 . Sorry to ask, I am a beginner here, would you mind explaining the last print statement?  print '\t{:20}: {}'.format(student.find('name').text, student.find('result').text) Thanks Dawg..

Comment: It is the Python format [mini language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 0):

Your code for printing a tag value is correct, but you are asking for a section of your xml that does not exist.  There is no female section in the second student section.  This is why `student.find("female/result")` is returning `None` on the second student, and you cannot call `.text` on a `None` object.